# How does Node expose functions written in C so they're available in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to explain how modules written in C are "exposed" and made available to javascript in Node. **Edit:** and I don't mean exposed like with `require`.  It's kind of perplexing how something written in javascript can communicate with something written in C. 
For example:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

My assumption is that at some point the method `readFile` communicates with its C-equivalent to do the operation.  At some point the javascript or C code registers the callback with the event loop.

So I end up with two questions 1) Is the communication between my javascript call to `fs.readFile` communicating with the C-equivalent via my javascript being compiled into something that C recognizes or something else?  and 2) Is V8 registering the callback from `fs.readFile` or does it do that from the C module that `fs.readFile` communicates with?

Comment: Look at `src/node_file.cc` and `lib/fs.js` in the node source. Also look at _how Node/V8 C++ extensions are written_ that will explain all of it.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks for the reference and I have no problem doing the heavy lifting to try and figure this out.  I'm unfortunately not a C++ programmer, but I will endeavor :)  Am I on the right track that somehow compiled C++ methods can somehow be called after the javascript is compiled?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's done in the native Node libraries, but anything that can be done at the command line can be invoked / communicated with using child process's spawn or exec methods (I think -- this isn't something I've had to do often so I'm unsure of its limitations). http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: 1. something else: the host environment provides that method. 2. v8 registers it to run when the C++ is done.